# Editing to improve search results

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The question "[What is the reason behind "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290884/what-is-the-reason-behind-non-static-method-cannot-be-referenced-from-a-static)" is currently the canonical question regarding the error "non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context".

I noticed that it shows up for the following searches, for example:

- "non-static static context [java]"
- "non static static context [java]"

But it does *not* show up for:

- "nonstatic static context [java]"

It does not contain the word "nonstatic". While that third form is arguably ugly, it's still a valid search term. On a few occasions I've noticed that this prevents that question from showing up in the "related" links when posters use the word "nonstatic" when describing the error. It also affects the related questions that pop up when asking a new question.

I want to edit the question to add the word "nonstatic" to improve search results, but I am not quite sure what the best way to do it is.

I could simply add, e.g., "Search keyword: nonstatic" to the bottom of the question, but that feels sloppy.

What's the best way to do this without adding noise to the question?

Comment: IMO this should be changed on the search engine, not individual questions (Google, for example, will insert and remove spaces just about anywhere (among other changes) to give you the thing you were most likely to have been searching for).